# Basic Auth / JWT Token, removing Basic Auth popup

Tags: spring-security, http-status-code-401

I use the combination of basic auth and spring security (JWT token) (Springboot)

I have the following setup:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <display-name>det</display-name>
    <description>det</description>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>images</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <!-- OMIT auth-constraint -->
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>User</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

So the login service returns a JWT token.  Then spring security takes over and uses the token to validate the use of rest services.

This all works.  I only have one problem.  When the user sends wrong credentials I get a 401 error and the popup auth shows up.  I want to avoid this.  I tried using a filter to change the response code, but it does not seem to be triggered.

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, used an error servlet for 401 errors and removed the WWW-Authenticate value from the response header